Net dipole moment of identical-particle system
Let $N$ identical electric charges be arranged arbitrarily in space, in such a way that each of them has a fixed position $\vec{r}_i$, a charge $q$ and a mass $m$. If I were to calculate the total dipole moment of said distribution ($\vec{p}_T$), then I could proceed as follows, taking into account dipole moments are additive magnitudes:
$$\vec{p}_T=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N \vec{p}_i=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N q_i\vec{r}_i$$
Since the charges are, by hypothesis, identical, they have the same charge and mass, so I can take $q$ out of the summation. Also, I'm interested in writing this sum in terms of the position of the center of mass of the distribution:
$$\vec{p}_T=q\left(\frac{1}{M_T}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N m\vec{r}_i\right)\frac{M_T}{m}$$
Where $M_T$ is the total mass of the distribution. The term inside the parenthesis can easily be identified as the system's center of mass ($\vec{r}_{CM}$), so I can write this expression more compactly as follows:
$$\vec{p}_T=q\ \vec{r}_{CM}\frac{M_T}{m}$$
since the particles are identical, they all contribute the same to the system's total mass, so evidently we have: $M_T=Nm$. Substituting this into our equation:
$$\vec{p}_T=Nq\ \vec{r}_{CM}$$
And if we define $\vec{p}_{CM}\equiv q\vec{r}_{CM}$ as the dipole moment possessed by a particle of charge $q$ such as those present in the system and placed in the center of mass, we then get:
$$\vec{p}_T=N\vec{p}_{CM}$$
Therefore, although each charge in my system is randonly oriented, the total dipole moment is identical to another system with the same number of particles in which all of the dipoles are oriented in the same direction. What are the implications of this?

In your first sentence, do you mean a set of charges, not a set of dipoles? In addition, you might be running into the issue that if the electric monopole moment is non-zero, then that means that the dipole moment is not unique: it depends on the choice of coordinates (and origin of that coordinate system), which makes it difficult to compare the dipole moments for two different situations.

@march right you are, I meant charges!

Everything you've written is correct. But it's not clear what the question is. "What are the implications of this?" is too broad for this site.

@EmilioPisanty thanks for your feedback! My question would be "why does it look like, despite my charges being randomly distributed (and therefore their dipole moments randomly oriented), I still get a net dipole moment as if all the dipole moments in my system had the same orientation"

"Dipole moment" is a different name for "electric moment" which is best used when we talk about electrically neutral system, because then electric moment is really a property of the system, independent of the choice of origin of the coordinate system.  A system of charges of the same sign can be ascribed electric moment as you did, but notice this depends on the choice of origin. You can rewrite it as you did, but this does not mean any single particle can be ascribed dipole moment in direction of $\mathbf r_{CM}$ in the standard sense.

It is similar to taking the average of a set of random numbers and getting a particular number as result, which is then also equal to the average of N copies of an identical number (the average itself!)
Only here the numbers are vectors, but for each of their coordinates this is what happens.
What does it imply? Apparently, for some purposes (lake taking the average) we can, if we want, replace things by their average in advance. But for other purposes (like finding the variance) we certainly cannot do that. Sometimes individual differences matter, sometimes not...
